# Swift - Getting the count of all arrays in an array of custom object

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of custom object "Foo".

Each "Foo" has an optional array of "Bar".

I know I could do it using for loops but I'm hoping for a more elegant way, possibly using flatMap, filter and/or reduce.

Foo can have more properties of different types.

```
class Foo {
   var bars: [Bar]?
}

let foo1 = Foo()
let foo2 = Foo()
let foo3 = Foo()

let bar1 = Bar()
let bar2 = Bar()
let bar3 = Bar()

foo1.bars.append(bar2)
foo1.bars.append(bar3)

foo2.bars.append(bar1)
foo2.bars.append(bar2)
foo2.bars.append(bar3)

foo3.bars.append(bar1)
foo3.bars.append(bar2)

let FooArray = [Foo1, Foo2, Foo3]
// Magic -> Print 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce`

```
let count = FooArray.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.bars?.count ?? 0) }
```

Paste this in playground

```
class Bar {

}
class Foo {
    var bars: [Bar]?

    func appendBar(_ bar: Bar) {
        if self.bars == nil {
            self.bars = [bar]
        } else {
            self.bars!.append(bar)
        }
    }
}

let foo1 = Foo()
let foo2 = Foo()
let foo3 = Foo()

let bar1 = Bar()
let bar2 = Bar()
let bar3 = Bar()

foo1.appendBar(bar2)
foo1.appendBar(bar3)

foo2.appendBar(bar1)
foo2.appendBar(bar2)
foo2.appendBar(bar3)

foo3.appendBar(bar1)
foo3.appendBar(bar2)

let FooArray = [foo1, foo2, foo3]
let count = FooArray.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.bars?.count ?? 0) }
print(count) // Output: 7
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I would suggest you to make your `Foo` model `struct` instead and initalize empty `Array` instead of declaring optional array

```
struct Bar {}

struct Foo {
    var bars = [Bar]()
}
```

Then you can use `reduce`. Add number of elements inside `bars` array of each `Foo` to sum.

```
let count = fooArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.bars.count }
```

---

```
var foo1 = Foo()
var foo2 = Foo()
var foo3 = Foo()

foo1.bars = [Bar(),Bar()]
foo2.bars = [Bar(),Bar(),Bar()]
foo3.bars = [Bar(),Bar()]

let fooArray = [foo1, foo2, foo3]
let count = fooArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.bars.count }
print(count) // 7
```

---

If you want to keep type of `bars` as optional array, you can just add `0` to sum

```
let count = fooArray.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.bars?.count ?? 0) }
```

Comment: How exactly do I add a 0?
`let count = fooArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.bars?.count ?? 0}`

Comment: @Tarek sorry. I forgot for `()`. See edit: `{ $0 + ($1.bars?.count ?? 0) }`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change Foo as Robert Dresler suggests. This will work just fine:

```
let count = fooArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.bars?.count ?? 0 }
```